# Exception in Visual studio code output window

Tags: visual-studio

In VS2022 console, errors do not output specific code locations, only runtime error messages. This makes it very inconvenient for me to locate issues. How can I configure this?

I couldn't find relevant information on the internet. I'm a beginner in using VS. How should I proceed?